When can I book German train tickets for January 2025?
I would like to plan a train travel for the end of January 2025. I see here that Deutsche Bahn train tickets can usually be booked online 91 days in advance. Some people say 92 to 180 days. However, as of today 25/09/2024 is not possible to buy DB tickets after December 14th.
Does anyone know when those tickets will go on sale?

The 2025 schedule (for all railways in Europe) starts on December 15th, which is probably the reason for this. There's always a bit of disruption each year (as despite a lot of planning there are often changes quite late), and it's difficult to know exactly when they will be open to reservation. In many cases it actually opens in stages with not all trains available at the same time.

At the time of writing, you will be able to buy tickets for after Dec 15th starting October 16th. (https://bahngebote.de/buchungsstart-neuer-fahrplan/)
Also please note that DB said they will relax the 91 days restriction to 12 months in advance.

Would be great if you could add a sentence, as to why this is. Usually the new schedules for the next year get released around mid december. I think otherwise you could buy tickets up to 6 months ahead.

You mean the 12 months?

Not sure where you got that info from. But in Google it says "Seit vielen Jahren gilt: Tickets für die Deutsche Bahn lassen sich maximal 6 Monate im Voraus buchen. Und das auch nur dann, wenn nicht gerade der Fahrplanwechsel ansteht." Which says, usually you can book 6 months ahead, unless the schedule change is less than 6 months ahead. That's also why I said, it would be good if you explain, why it is only 91 days in this case. Which the reason is "schedule change for the year 2025 is in mid of december and they don't know the new schedule, so you can't book further ahead"

For example here: https://travel-dealz.de/news/bahn-vorausbuchungsfrist-2024/
